# Cannot find 'selectedIndexPaths' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My Viewcontroller shows "Cannot find 'selectedIndexPaths' in scope" and other errors

My viewcontroller with errors:- import UIKit

```
  class ProductViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,
                         UITableViewDelegate {
   let notificationButton = SSBadgeButton()
    let rightbarbuttonimage = UIImage(named:"ic_cart")
    fileprivate var cart = Cart()
   let scrollView = UIScrollView()
   let sections = ["Section A", "Section B","Section C", "Section D","Section   E","Section F","Section G","Section H", "Section I","Section J","Section K","Section L"]
   let rowspersection = [2,3,1,2,2,3,3,1,4,2,1,2]


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    
    //Add and setup scroll view
    self.tableView.addSubview(self.scrollView)
    self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    
    //Constrain scroll view
    self.scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true;
    self.scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true;
    self.scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true;
    self.scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true;
    
    // customising rightBarButtonItems as notificationbutton
    notificationButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44)
    notificationButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_cart")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
    notificationButton.badgeEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 15)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: notificationButton)
    
    
    
    //following register is needed because I have rightbarbuttonitem customised as   uibutton i.e.  notificationbutton
    notificationButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.registerTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}
@objc func registerTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCart", sender: nil)
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    
    
    
    //Workaround to avoid the fadout the right bar button item
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
    
    //Update cart if some items quantity is equal to 0 and reload the product table and right button bar item
    cart.updateCart()
    
    
    //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Checkout (\(cart.items.count))"
    notificationButton.badge = String(cart.items.count)// making badge equal to no.ofitems in cart
    
    tableView.reloadData()
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

// this segue to transfer data
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showCart" {
        if let cartViewController = segue.destination as? CartViewController {
            cartViewController.cart = self.cart
        }
    }
}

   func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return productMap.count
   }
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return productMap[section]?.count ?? 0
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let product = productMap[indexPath.section]![indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductTableViewCell") as! ProductTableViewCell
    cell.imageView?.image =  product.imagename
    cell.delegate = self as CartDelegate
    cell.setButton(state: self.cart.contains(product: product))
    return cell
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    
    switch(section) {
    case 0: return "Section A"
    case 1: return "Section B"
    case 2: return "Section C"
    case 3: return "Section D"
    case 4: return "Section E"
    case 5: return "Section F"
    case 6: return "Section G"
    case 7: return "Section H"
    case 8: return "Section I"
    case 9: return "Section J"
    case 10: return "Section K"
    case 11: return "Section L"
    default: return ""
       }
    }
  }



     extension ProductViewController: CartDelegate {

     // MARK: - CartDelegate
    func updateCart(cell: ProductTableViewCell) {
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
    let product = productMap[indexPath.section]![indexPath.row]
    
 /// `var selectedIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()` defined inside `ProductViewController`,   to keep track of the selected products// **error -Cannot find 'selectedIndexPaths' in scope**
    if selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {**//error -Cannot find 'selectedIndexPaths' in scope**
        if let index = selectedIndexPaths.firstIndex(of: indexPath) {
            selectedIndexPaths.remove(at: index)**//error -Cannot find 'selectedIndexPaths' in scope**
            removeProductFromCart(indexPath: indexPath)
        }
    } else {
        selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
        addProductToCart(indexPath: indexPath)
    }
    
         //           addProductToCart(indexPath: indexPath)
    ///  **I commented this out because I don't have the code for `Cart`**
    //Update Cart with product
         //        cart.updateCart(with: product)
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Checkout (\(cart.items.count))"
        //        notificationButton.badge = String(cart.items.count) // making badge equal to noofitems in cart
    
      }
     }

    func addProductToCart(indexPath: IndexPath) {
     if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ProductTableViewCell {
    if let imageView = cell.imagename {
        
        let initialImageViewFrame = imageView.convert(imageView.frame, to: self.view)
        let targetImageViewFrame = self.notificationButton.frame
        
        let imgViewTemp = UIImageView(frame: initialImageViewFrame)
        imgViewTemp.clipsToBounds = true
        imgViewTemp.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imgViewTemp.image = imageView.image
        
        self.view.addSubview(imgViewTemp)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            imgViewTemp.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
        }) {  _ in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                imgViewTemp.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.2, y: 0.2).rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi))
                imgViewTemp.frame = targetImageViewFrame
            }) { _ in
                imgViewTemp.removeFromSuperview()

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
                    self.notificationButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.4, y: 1.4)
                }, completion: {_ in
                    self.notificationButton.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                })
            }
          }
        }
         }
        }

  func removeProductFromCart(indexPath: IndexPath) {
   if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ProductTableViewCell {
    if let imageView = cell.imagename {
        
        let initialImageViewFrame = self.notificationButton.frame
        let targetImageViewFrame = imageView.convert(imageView.frame, to: self.view)
        
        let imgViewTemp = UIImageView(frame: initialImageViewFrame)
        imgViewTemp.clipsToBounds = true
        imgViewTemp.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imgViewTemp.image = imageView.image
        
        self.view.addSubview(imgViewTemp)
        
        var initialTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        initialTransform = initialTransform.scaledBy(x: 0.2, y: 0.2)
        initialTransform = initialTransform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi))
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.notificationButton.animationZoom(scaleX: 1.4, y: 1.4)
            imgViewTemp.transform = initialTransform
        }) {  _ in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                self.notificationButton.animationZoom(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
                imgViewTemp.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                imgViewTemp.frame = targetImageViewFrame
            }) { _ in
                imgViewTemp.removeFromSuperview()
            }
           }
         }
      }
           }
```

screenshot of the error-

[image]

I have tableview in my productviewcotroller as shown below. so, thats not an issusem still errors:-
[image]

There are other errors also which it is showing.

How to sort it out ?

Comment: You have commented out ```/// `var selectedIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()` defined inside ProductViewController``` but it is actually not defined in ProductViewController at all.

Comment: And you should also take care indenting your code properly, some of it is actually outside the class (extension) instead of inside it.

Answer (score 0):

var selectedIndexPaths = IndexPath

Please define selectedIndexPaths inside the main class not in the extension then check it again .